# Python Toggle a program on/off with key press

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import time


start = 0

if keyboard.on_press("F7") and start == 0:
    start = 1
if keyboard.on_press("F7") and start == 1:
    start = 0

while start == 1:
    keyboard.write("a")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.send('enter')
    print(start)
```

When I run this, the process ends immediately. I am new to python, and don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with keyboard input, but, at a first glance, this won't run as you would expect it to.

What your program is doing, is setting `start` to `0`. Then, that same second (or whatever), it checks whether you are pressing F7 and `start == 0`. If both conditions are true, it sets `start` to `1`. Then it checks whether you are pressing F7 again and if `start` is `1`. If both conditions are true, `start` will be set to `0`. Every time it will result in `start` being `0`, since if you are pressing F7, it will be 0, and if you aren't pressing F7 it will be 0 as well.

After this, it stops checking for F7 and because `start` will always be `0`, it won't go into the while-loop. This is obviously not the intended behavior.

What you could do is a while-loop that runs forever (`while True`) and then checks every iteration whether you are pressing F7. If you pressed F7, set `start` to the opposite of what it was.

```py
while True:
    if start == 1:
        # do whatever it is you want it to do
    
    if keyboard.on_press("F7"):
        if start == 0:
            start = 1
        elif start == 1:
            start = 0

    sleep(1)
```

This will do what you want it to do, but it is also not a perfect solution, since you cannot hold F7 for longer than 1 second, or `start` will flip again. Also you must hold F7 until it stops sleeping and it checks for F7 again, which is also not perfect. However, it kind of does what you would like it to do.

Comment: When I run this, it is automatically turned on, and I am not able to turn it off

Also, it gave me an error about sleep(1). I changed it to time.sleep(1), so that may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code, all conditions are checked, and the process end. Use `while True` loop to repeat your process :

```
import keyboard
import time


start = 0

while True :
    if keyboard.on_press("F7") and start == 0:
        start = 1
    if keyboard.on_press("F7") and start == 1:
        start = 0

    while start == 1:
        keyboard.write("a")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.send('enter')
        print(start)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner, more reliable approach using keyboard's built-in add_hotkey method.

Below is a simple program to toggle printing of the current timestamp.

```
import keyboard as kb
from datetime import datetime as dt

global print_flag
print_flag = False

def toggle_print():
    global print_flag
    print_flag = not print_flag

kb.add_hotkey('d', toggle_print)

while True:
    timestamp = dt.now()
    if print_flag:
         print(timestamp)
```